# Spring boot actuator - Implement custom metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to implement custom metric or statistics to my spring boot rest web service using actuator but i am not able to find simple tutorials. 
For example:

- how to show how many times a certain controller was called and what exact parameter field was filled?
- how can i create a metric that when its URL is called, it runs certain query and shows back a json with some result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For point two the solution is to create an endpoint class (it can be or not a rest controller class). For example:

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "pfm-statistics")
public class StatisticsEndpoint {
  @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
     officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
  @ResponseBody
  public byte[] generateStatisticsAsExcel() {
 ...
```

Note that the ID is the path to be called from URL. We can create a simple endpoint too and just return a string if we want. In this case instead of @RestControllerEndpoint annotation we can use @Endpoint, as a side note, the id should always contain dash

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good scenario for AOP **(Aspect Oriented Programing)** as this will allow you to separate this statistic logic from the business logic.

Have a look at Spring doc for more info about AOP and how to achieve that with Spring.

You can then define a pointcut on your controller and have a service for counting (and probably then storing) the data.

Refer below link 
[AOP Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aspectj_based_aop_appoach.htm)